# How to upgrade mono on openSuse

Tags: linux, mono, installation, opensuse

I have a virtual machine running of openSuse 11.2 that has mono 2.6.4, I use this VM as a test server to test asp.net applications under Apache mod_mono.

I wanted to upgrade (in the same virtual machine) to mono 2.8.2. I downloaded several rpm files from http://ftp.novell.com/pub/mono/download-stable/openSUSE_11.2/i586/ but I'm in a dependency "loop", don't know which package to install in the correct order...

(Did I mention that I know very little of suse?)

Edit: Is it possible to find a way to upgrade it without network connectivity?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this question belongs elsewhere. Maybe in [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Superuser](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: My SuSE days are long gone, but from what I remember: Are you using Yast to install the RPM, or the rpm command line utility? Maybe adding the packages with cirular dependencies to your question would be helpful.

Comment: @Wagner You are right, this question belongs to Unix & Linux stackexchange, I created it there: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6488/how-to-upgrade-mono-on-opensuse Can I remove it from here?

Comment: There is an option to migrate a question to another Stack Exchange site, so the votes and stuff are kept. But I think you got to have enough reputation to do so. Since this is a new question without any votes and answers, I suppose there is no problem in deleting it.

Comment: Ops, seems you got yourself an answer! :) Maybe you should keep it here... well, it's up to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to [this page](http://software.opensuse.org/search?q=mono-complete&baseproject=openSUSE%3A11.2&lang=en&exclude_filter=home%3A&exclude_debug=true) at opensuse.org and click "1-Click Install" button on `mono-complete-2.8.2` meta package. Then all your loop dependencies will be solved automatically by YaST manager.

It is a usual user-friendly way to install packages on openSuSE.

Comment: The issue I am having is I only have ssh access to the server. So, going through a web browser and clicking on a 1-Click Install is not going to work for me.  Is there a way to run the YMP files in the shell?